# I can't access to my port 3000 form browser to docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, next.js

I have a dockerized Application with laravel, nginx and mysql. These are the docker-compose and dockerfiles

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'
services:

  # Application
  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    depends_on:
      - "db"

  # Web Server
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    depends_on:
      - "app"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "3000:3000"

  # Database
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

web.dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.21

COPY nginx/conf.d/app.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
   && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

EXPOSE 3000
```

app.dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    git curl gnupg \
    --no-install-recommends \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql -j$(nproc) gd

ENV NODE_VERSION=18.12.1
RUN apt install -y curl
ENV NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
RUN mkdir "/root/.nvm"
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm use v${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm alias default v${NODE_VERSION}
ENV PATH="/root/.nvm/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/bin/:${PATH}"
RUN node --version
RUN npm --version

RUN npm install -g yarn

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

USER $user

RUN cd client && yarn
```

When I run the `docker-compose up -d` and it finished I can access to localhost url. Now if I go to `docker exec -it app bash` and inside the container I change the directory `cd client` and run `npm run dev` it compiles and show me that the app is running in localhost:3000.

NOTE: In client I have a nextjs application

```
root@7ff9ccc2712e:/var/www/client# npm run dev

> next-file-now@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from /var/www/client/.env.local
event - compiled client and server successfully in 1794 ms (161 modules)
```

But if I try to access from browser to http://localhost:3000 I can't access

I tried the `EXPOSE 3000` Port, but it is still inaccessible. I'm expecting to access to the next js application

Comment: You're only forwarding port 3000 in your `web` service, not `app`. What does your NGINX config look like?

Comment: Hi @Phil this is my ngnix config file

``server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}``

Comment: Add `- "3000:3000"` in your app container docker-compose.yml and in your nginx file `listen 3000;`, but mixing npm/node inside your php container seems weird

Answer (score 0):

If you're unsure about the host running your web service and it's currently set to `localhost`, you can try changing it to:

```
host: '0.0.0.0'
```

This can help make your service accessible externally. Don't forget to update the port as well:

```
port: 3000
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).